# Get rid of Vscode's inline window on cmd click and navigate directly to code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, editor

I've updated my Vscode to 1.43 (from a few versions below) and now when I Cmd+Click any class/type etc in TypeScript, instead of navigating to its definition, I get this arguably worst designed popup "inline window" ever:

[image]

This ugly window comes up whenever I click `Response`. Before updating Vscode, it would just navigate to definition of `Response` normaly by opening the file that contains the symbol as a new tab.

How can I get back to the normal behavior and get rid of this weird behavior completely?

Comment: I think this is a peek window, you can edit inside this. Search the settings for `peek`

Comment: that did it. found the answer after searching for `peek`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following `rioV8`s advice in comments, I've searched for peek and found out that it can (fortunately) be disabled in `settings.json`. Adding `.vscode/settings.json` (or modifying it) file and putting the following solved the problem:

```
{
    "editor.gotoLocation.multipleDefinitions": "goto",
    "editor.gotoLocation.multipleDeclarations": "goto",
    "editor.gotoLocation.multipleImplementations": "goto",
    "editor.gotoLocation.multipleReferences": "goto",
    "editor.gotoLocation.multipleTypeDefinitions": "goto",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the top menu, click **Code** -> **Preferences** -> **Settings**

[image]

Then search for peak, and under **Text Editor**, set the following 5 settings to **goto**

- Editor › Goto Location: Multiple Declarations
- Editor › Goto Location: Multiple Definitions
- Editor › Goto Location: Multiple Implementations
- Editor › Goto Location: Multiple References
- Editor › Goto Location: Multiple Type Definitions

[image]